# I'm having five allocations for an object with only one alloc in the same function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, retaincount

I'm writing a function that only displays a menu (composed by a tableView) in a popOver.

This is the source code:

```
-(void)pushSearch:(NSString *)option type:(int)optionType
{
    searchNav = [[iNavigation alloc] initWithNibName:@"iNavigation" bundle:nil] ;
    //This is the UIViewController with the tableView

    [searchNav setSearchMode:optionType];

    searchNav.view.frame =CGRectMake(0,0,300,600);

    NSLog(@"Retain Count: %d",[searchNav retainCount]);
```

//At this point retain count is 1

```
    if ([pop isPopoverVisible])
    {
        [pop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        [pop release];
    }

    pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:searchNav];

    NSLog(@"Retain Count: %d",[searchNav retainCount]);
    //At this point retain count is 2



    [pop presentPopoverFromRect:btnMenu.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    [pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(350,600)];

    NSLog(@"Retain Count: %d",[searchNav retainCount]);
    //At this point retain count is 5!!!

    [searchNav release];

}
```

The problem that I'm having is that the used memory to load the tableview is never released. My app grows and grows in memory until crashes.

Why if only i'm making one allocation for searchNav, after assign it to the popOver the reatin count is 5?

Please any help?

Answer (score 4):

## Do not use -retainCount.

The absolute retain count of an object is meaningless.

You should call `release` exactly same number of times that you caused the object to be retained.  No less (unless you like leaks) and, certainly, no more (unless you like crashes).

See the [Memory Management Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) for full details.

---

That the retain count is 5 is irrelevant and quite likely because of internal implementation details of the various frameworks.

The memory management of `searchNav` in that code is correct;  you allocated the object (+1 retain) and then you eventually released it (-1 retain).   Therefore, the memory leak is somewhere else.

Try using "build and analyze" on your source.   Then use the Allocations instrument to have a look at the objects that are hanging about  as your app grows over time.   There is an over-retain somewhere;  a retain for which you haven't balanced it with a release.

Comment: Can we just have the `[retaincount]` tag automatically redirect to `[retaincount-is-evil-stopit-stopit-stop]`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you release the `UIPopoverController` ? Perhaps that object is still retaining the table view.